# Is Java SwingWorker cancellation cooperative?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

Would appreciate any help in understanding this.  My understanding is that cancellation of a SwingWorker thread is cooperative.  However, that isn't what I'm seeing.

I have code below that will stop the SwingWorker thread even though I have no operations that are interruptable.  I wouldn't expect it to work this way.  Note for the test that I have specifically put an infinite loop in doStuff().   When I do the cancellation in the main() routine:

worker.cancel(true),

I end up in the done() function indicating that doInBackground() exited (specifically in the Exception handler).  It looks like the thread is being killed even in the absence of an interruptable operation.  Note if I change to worker.cancel(false), I get the same effect.

```
class AWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Entered doStuff");    
        while (true);
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        //System.out.println("doInBackground started");
        doStuff();
        return "hello";
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            System.out.println("done() entered");
            String status = get();
            System.out.println("done(): get = " + status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("done(): Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AWorker worker = new AWorker();
        worker.execute();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        worker.cancel(true);

    }
}
```

I should add that I can make this work exactly as described in the Java documentation by cooperatively putting in a sleep that gets interrupted when I cancel or by polling isCancelled().  Just wondering why it does it what it does in my code snippet above.  If I were to hazard a guess, it looks like when I call worker.cancel() without the cooperative mechanisms just described, then the done() function immediately gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [SwingWorker.done()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done--) method seems to be a bit wrong. It says that done() is called "after the doInBackground method is finished". But, firstly, done() is also apparently called when you cancel the SwingWorker, even if you never started it. Secondly, if you cancel the SwingWorker then done() is called immediately, even if the doInBackground() method hasn't returned yet. That's what's happening here.

When done() is called, your infinite loop is still running. I confirmed that using the following code which dumps all thread stack traces to the console:

```
static void dumpThreads() {
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(t.getKey() + ":");
        for (StackTraceElement e : t.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("    " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I inserted a call to that method inside done(). One of the thread stack traces showed that the infinite loop was still alive and well at that time:

```
Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main]:
    AWorker.doStuff(AWorker.java:8)
    AWorker.doInBackground(AWorker.java:14)
    javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

However, the infinite loop does get forcibly stopped shortly afterwards, not by the SwingWorker, but by the end of the program, because when there are no non-daemon threads running (SwingWorker threads are daemon threads) and no windows created, the program exits. The combination of those two things (dodgy documentation and automatic exit) gives the appearance that cancelling the SwingWorker is magically stopping the task, but it isn't.

If you open a window from your main method, that will prevent the program from automatically exiting. Then you'll see from your system task manager that the program stays running (and stays hogging the CPU in that infinite loop) until you terminate it.

In short, yes, SwingWorker cancellation **is** cooperative.

Comment: Very instructive analysis that shows that doInBackground is still actually executing after SwingWorker is cancelled.  

It would be great if the Java documentation were updated to more accurately reflect what happens.  I made an attempt to file a bug report but the Oracle process for filing bugs is pretty gruesome.